# Using others' figures, illustrations, and diagrams

Tags: citations, copyright, graphics

I am writing up a chapter of a literature review and I thought to add two figures to illustrate the theory of that subject of my research. These two figures are available in the literature and they are well known. My question is: if I used these figures with complete references to the authors, would that be acceptable in the APA style?

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct issues at play here: copyright and intellectual honesty.

- From an intellectual honest point of view, it is entirely acceptable to reproduce a figure provided that you clearly credit the original source.
- Copyright, however, is an entirely separate legal issue, and the figures that you wish to use may or may not be available to you under a license that will allow you to use them (or use them cheaply).

Comment: If this paper is being written for a class project, copyright probably isn't an issue you should worry about.  In anything intended for publication or even an MS thesis or PhD dissertation it would normally be necessary to get permission from the original publisher.  For example, the graduate office at my institution demands signed releases for any material in a thesis that has been taken from other publications in this way.    Another option would be to redraw the figure and cite the figure as "based on figure xxx in (Jones 2013)"